# Differentiating between threads, even though they have the same name

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a very simple Java game involving a player and randomly moving bots. The player can add bots to the map by pressing a button, which in turn creates a new thread for the bot.

So it looks something like this...

```
Thread newBotThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
```

If I press the button several times, several bots are created, are they all run under the thread name 'newBotThread'? I'm adding functions which allow the player to interact with the bots, Is there a way of differentiating between the threads, even though they all have the same name? So i could stop one bot, while the others still continue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this code running inside the event handler for the "add bot" button?  If so, how would you access the variable outside of that block even with only one bot?  I'd consider have a field in your game class that is a collection of bots, and the event handler adds threads to this collection.

Comment: Each thread has a unique `Thread.getId()`

Answer (score 2):

You could add them to a `Collection`, such as `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Thread> botThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
...
botThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
...
```

Of course you should declare `botThreads` somewhere where it's accesible to the rest of your class(es), so outside of your button-event-handler.

Comment: How come I'm unable to print 'Thread.getId()'? It says I cannot reference a non-static variable from a static context

Comment: `Thread.getId()` is not a static method, you'll need to call it on an actual `Thread`-object. Like `botThreads.get(0).getId()`

Answer (score 0):

short answer: there is a method Thread#setName(String) and a constructor Thread(String) that set the thread´s name and must be set before invoking start() method.

long answer: you quite probably shouldn´t be using this name to control your bots. i suggest creating a class that implements Runnable which contains methods such as go(), stop(), continue(), or whatever you need, and whenever you create new instances of these class you keep the reference somewhere (maybe a Map or BotManager or whatever) and also you probably should execute them with an Executor. Just my opinion